# Can't move items in a linearlayout

Tags: java, android

I created a linear vertical layout, but when I add items to it, I can only move it up or down or increase the size to the right :

Screenshot of my layout

[image: Screenshot of my layout]

I'm not even sure how I got my textview to be padded on the left side!
I tried padding, which does work BUT surely there is something I am doing wrong which is stopping me from moving the items around with a bit more control?

my xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCreateAutomateGame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AutomateGameButtonPickPlayers"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_edge_button"
            android:text="@string/pickPlayers"
            android:textColor="@color/veniceblue"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="259dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAutomateGameComposeMessage"
            android:layout_width="215dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/composeMessage"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColorHint="@color/softwhite"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that's what linear layouts are meant for: rendering items one after the other. what do you want to achieve, by the way? so we can help you giving some suggestions

Comment: I want to be able to move my button to the right or left but it won't let me move it to the right freely. I may need to just stick to padding...

Comment: This is the default behavior of LinearLayout.You can use `android:gravity` or `android:layout_gravity` to align the content or views respectively as per your needs.If you want more flexibility use RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCreateAutomateGame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="104dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AutomateGameButtonPickPlayers"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="74dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="259dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAutomateGameComposeMessage"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/composeMessage"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColorHint="@color/softwhite"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**========= EDIT for placing button to right side of screen ==========**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCreateAutomateGame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AutomateGameButtonPickPlayers"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAutomateGameComposeMessage"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/composeMessage"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColorHint="@color/softwhite"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**[Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity) - Standard constants and tools for placing an object within a potentially larger container.**

Comment: Nope, still can't move it to the right in design view. I might just stick to adding padding/margin as you described

Comment: @trig try edit 2 if you want button on right side of screen